# Node js Get folder path from a file

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, npm

Is there a way to get the path to a folder that holds a particular file.

```
fs.realpathSync('config.json', []);
```

returns something like

```
G:\node-demos\7-node-module\demo\config.json
```

I just need

```
G:\node-demos\7-node-module\demo\ 
or
G:\node-demos\7-node-module\demo\
```

Is there any api for this or will I need to process the string?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

use [path.dirname](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p)

```
// onlyPath should be G:\node-demos\7-handlebars-watch\demo
var onlyPath = require('path').dirname('G:\\node-demos\\7-node-module\\demo\\config.json');
```

Comment: Double your backslashes, or you’ll end up escaping random characters.

Comment: if you're starting with a relative path like in the original question, you would do- `let onlyPath = path.dirname(fs.realpathSync('config.json'));`

Comment: I would want to always use @Kip method of using `realpathSync` which covers absolute and relative paths

Comment: Just to add a warning on this. If your path doesn't have a file name on the end (i.e your using the same code for multiple things) it will just strip off the last directory in your path instead. It's a dumb function which works well if you're 100% sure the file path has a file in it.

Comment: @webnoob You could see it as it being dumb, or you could see it as it giving the directory  that contains that directory. It's not wrong. That "dumb" behaviour is exactly what you want. Did you want it to be impossible to get the name of the directory that contains a directory?

Comment: @doug65536 I don't mean dumb in terms of "stupid", I mean it in programming terms of having one job and doing only that one job with the fixed data sent in. It won't make life easy for you :)

Answer (score 6):

`require("path").dirname(……)` **breaks** when your path does not explicitly specify its directory.

```
require("path").dirname("./..")
// "."
```

---

You may consider using `require("path").join(……, "../")` instead. It preserves the trailing separator as well.

```
require("path").join("whatever/absolute/or/relative", "../")
// "whatever/absolute/or/" (POSIX)
// "whatever\\absolute\\or\\" (Windows)
```

```
require("path").join(".", "../")
// "../" (POSIX)
// "..\\" (Windows)
```

```
require("path").join("..", "../")
// "../../" (POSIX)
// "..\\..\\" (Windows)
```

```
require("path").win32.join("C:\\", "../")
// "C:\\"
```